# Solr schema recommendations for multi-valued data with dates

Tags: solr, solrj

I have been tasked with extending a medical information database to include additional functionality for searching patient data.  The existing database uses Solr to store and query data such as birth date and symptoms:

```
patient
{
   birth date : date
   symptoms:
      heart disease
      diabetes
      neuropathy
   heart disease onset : date
   diabetes onset : date
   neuropathy onset : date
}
```

We want to extend this database to include more granular information by visit date, e.g.:

```
patient
{
   birth date : date
   symptoms:
      heart disease
      diabetes
      neuropathy
   heart disease onset : date
   diabetes onset : date
   neuropathy onset : date
   visit date 1 : date
      weight : float
      systolic blood pressure : int
      HbA1c : float
   visit date 2 : date
      weight : float
      height : float
      systolic blood pressure : int
}
```

There is no guarantee that all parameters will be present at all visits.  The goal is to be able to query medical data over time ranges, such as:
Return all patients with heart disease whose systolic blood pressure increased by 20 over 5 years.

I'm an experienced programmer but new to Solr.  It does not appear that Solr supports attaching a date field to other fields.  I've thought about 3 different approaches to the schema:

1. Multi-value fields, but I don't see how this can also store the associated visit date.

```
field name="weight" type="float" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
```

2. Multi-value visit fields with parameters stored in the visit.  I don't see how Solr can query within the date parameter.

```
field name="visit" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"
visit
{
   date
   weight : float
   systolic blood pressure : int
   HbA1c : float
}
```

3. Concatenate all data into a single field with a separator.

```
"visit-date:01012019|weight:float|height:float|HbA1c:float"
```

Any schema assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

There is only so much you can do with nested data in Solr. Another approach that you could take is to break down the information, for example on Solr document for the patient and one Solr document per-visit. Using your data this would look more or less as follow:

```
patient
{
   patient-id: 123
   birth date : date
   symptoms:
      heart disease
      diabetes
      neuropathy
   heart disease onset : date
   diabetes onset : date
   neuropathy onset : date
}

visit 1
{
  patient-id: 123
  visit date: date
  weight : float
  systolic blood pressure : int
  HbA1c : float
}

visit 2
{
  patient-id: 123
  visit date: date
  weight : float
  systolic blood pressure : int
  HbA1c : float
}
```

The problem here would be that the (total) patient information will be spread out through multiple Solr documents and that might complicate other queries. You could use Solr grouping to handle some of this but still, it would require some thought.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this approach and see how far I can get.  It will probably require some post-processing of the query as well